# limit Column number in Matrix using RDLC

Tags: asp.net, report, rdlc

I hope you will understand me :)

I'm using RDLC report and using Matrix table, but I dont know how to limit number of Columns in Matrix, I need only 5 Columns on each Matrix table.

**What I want looks like:**

[image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DibnJ.png)

The data in each table are different from the other tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Columns are defined manually in rdlc table. If you are generating then dinamically, maybe you are are grouping tables. If that is the case then the logic to define a max columns(groups) is in the method that generates de table datasource